# How to control a matrix of electromagnets

Tags: power-electronics, matrix

I'm trying to design a matrix of electromagnets, but I'm having trouble on figuring out the control schematic. I need to control the 12V 70mA coils using an Arduino Uno (5V 40mA max output).

Originally I was thinking of each coil having a transistor and it being controlled by shift registers, but that amount of transistors and signals (1 transistor and 1 shift register pin for each coil basically) is quite a lot, especially since my matrix is 18x10.

My next idea was using optoisolators to use standard multiplexing but have it act as a transistor. Each coil would have one, and I was fine with this because it minimizes signals (only row and column signals). The problem is that I could not find an optoisolator that could by itself handle the load. So I had to include a complementary transistor and resistor, which made the PCB extremely clogged and will make me sad when I have to solder everything together (180 times).

Is there a way to use multiplexing or something that can reduce the amount of components I have to use.

If it helps, I will never have more than 1 coil on at the time in each column.

Comment: Why can't you use shift registers and transistors in a multiplexed configuration?

Comment: @MattYoung Sinking the current in the columns is no problem using transistors, but Im not sure how to source the current using transistors.

Comment: This is not possible as a MUX can only have 1 cluster on at a time without a latch or memory

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Sorry I made a mistake in my wording, I meant one at a time, and only 3 on throughout the entire multiplexing routine. I will edit

Comment: Yes you better make more accurate specs

Comment: @JaredCohen The same exact way, with a complementary transistor.

Comment: @MattYoung Could you post a schematic of what you mean? I have tried but as far as Im aware using a high-side switch with a transistor is possible with a PNP, but to turn it off I need to use 12V? I am somewhat new to transistors so when it comes to this I am lost.

Comment: absent mechanical details your shift-register and transitrors plan seems the only viable way to do it. uness you can change the mechanical system to allow you to use permanent magnets that can be rearranged by magnetic pulses.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the mechanical system to use permanent magnets?

Comment: The fact that the ATMega specifies an absolute maximum pin current of 40mA **does not** mean that you can actually get 40mA from any given pin or that the voltage would be any higher than zero if you could. You need to look at the \$I_{OL}\$ and \$I_{OH}\$ specifications.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson last time I looked Vol/IOL was around 25 Ohms with the typical 50% tolerance so you actually do get 3.3V/25R=132mA ... much more than 40 mA with Vol into 3.3V but not that would want to that more than 1ms.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Well, Vol=0.6V with Iol of 10mA for Vcc=3V so more like 60 ohms, but that is for small values of Vds, where the transistors are still in their linear mode. If you try to draw large currents the transistors will enter saturation and act more like a constant current source than a resistor. And even if you could sink 40mA, or 132mA, that wouldn't be at a voltage anywhere near Vol so the output signal wouldn't be of much use as a pulldown.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t read.  Uno is 5V logic Which is 50 Ohm logic so 100mA Isc might be expect for Iol. indeed the datasheet for ATMEGA8 says 5V Iol=70mA @ 2V @ 20’C on Fig 0-17 @ElliotAlderson with anticipated IOL @ 5V as Expected 50 Ohm nom for 5V Logic and 25 Ohms for 3.6V max logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shift register and transistor concept. The voltage drop due to the MOSFET on resistance will be lower than Vce of a BJT in saturation, so I use MOSFETs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIXBBP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There are also dedicated ICs, commonly used in driving LEDs, such as the [NPIC6C4894](https://www.nexperia.cn/products/analog-logic-ics/i-o-expansion-logic/shift-registers/series/NPIC6C4894.html) which is a 12-bit parallel output shift register with 100 mA open drain outputs with 30 VDS. The phrase I used to find it in Google was *"12v open drain shift register"*.

This at least takes care of the low side. Considering their price and the scale of your project (I imagine 180 electromagnets don't come cheaply) you could just plop down 15 of them on the PCB and be done with it.